# Divergence with lookahead RegExp

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a test where all links that don't have 'investing' and 'news' are rejected, but I'm not understanding the logic of ?= and ?!, and I believe I'm doing something wrong since the opposite of the logic below is not being matched. Could someone give me a light?

Note: I could just use `!`, but I would like to understand what the error of this expression is.

```js
const positiveTest = x => (/(?=.*investing)(?=.*news)/).test(x);
const negativeTest = x => (/(?!.*investing)(?!.*news)/).test(x);

//if 'investing' and 'news' are found
console.log('positiveTest:')
console.log(positiveTest('https://br.investing.com/news/'));
console.log(positiveTest('https://br.investing.com/nws/'));
console.log(positiveTest('https://br.inveting.com/news/'));

//if 'investing' and 'news' are not found
console.log('negativeTest:')
console.log(negativeTest('https://br.investing.com/news/'));
console.log(negativeTest('https://br.investing.com/nws/'));
console.log(negativeTest('https://br.inveting.com/news/'));
```

Comment: Here's the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet#other_assertions

Comment: thanks @2pichar, but I understand the funcionality of these lookaheads, but not the divergence error(that shouldn't happen if they're opposite expressions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a while ago I understood the reason for this expression is wrong,

**Lookahead/Lookbehind needs a reference** to search, and if you don't put(or have) a reference, it will tests each index of the string like a `.(?=)`/`.(?!)`. Being so, the boundary expression `^` and `.*` is necessary at the beginning to prevent that *lookahead* tests each index of the string.

a more efficient way of writing this *generalized positive lookahead* is `(?=investing|news)`, but *generalized negative lookahead* is not viable because it requires more expressions (Ex: `^(?=.*(?:investing|news))`) It is more viable and efficient to invert a *positive lookahead* with the NOT `!` operator.

Answer (score 2):

Testing whether a string matches a regular expression will test whether *any individual position* in the string matches the regular expression. For example

```
/x/
```

matches

```
'fooxbar'
```

starting at index 3 of the string.

Your

```
/(?!.*investing)(?!.*news)/
```

will match all strings - namely, at the first position after which neither `investing` nor `news` exist. If both substrings are not in the target string, this will be at the start of the string. Otherwise, if both substrings this will be the position just past where the last one of them starts. For example, against:

```
https://br.investing.com/news/
```

it will match at this position:

```
https://br.investing.com/news/
                          ^
```

because starting at the `e` of `news`, it's true that neither `investing` nor `news` exist.

If you want to fix it, you can require the match to start at the beginning of the string, so that the lookaheads span the whole length of the string.

```js
const negativeTest = x => (/^(?!.*investing)(?!.*news)/).test(x);
//                          ^ use the ^ anchor
//if 'investing' and 'news' are not found
console.log('negativeTest:')
console.log(negativeTest('https://br.investing.com/news/'));
console.log(negativeTest('https://br.investing.com/nws/'));
console.log(negativeTest('https://br.inveting.com/news/'));
console.log(negativeTest('foobar'));
```

If you want the pattern to check that *both* do not exist, but one or the other is OK, then you'll need to alternate: match (negatively) the first phrase followed by the second, or the second followed by the first.

```js
const negativeTest = x => (/^(?!.*investing.*news|.*news.*investing)/).test(x);
console.log('negativeTest:')
console.log(negativeTest('https://br.investing.com/news/'));
console.log(negativeTest('https://br.investing.com/nws/'));
console.log(negativeTest('https://br.inveting.com/news/'));
console.log(negativeTest('foobar'));
```

Comment: the result has improved, but it still does not correspond to the opposite of ``?=``. as you can see, he should consider the other two positions as 'true' but he didn't. I understand the pointer part, but  not this divergence

Comment: Do you want to check that both don't exist, but one or the other is OK? Alternate between the two possible orders of the phrases then.